# Why Ubuntu does not recognize second hard drive when uploading image to Instagram etc

Tags: upload, instagram

Why Ubuntu does not allow me to select and upload an image to Instagram from the second hard drive on dual boot system? Only workaround I have found is to move the image to Ubuntu image folder on the drive where Ubuntu is installed and then upload it from there. The other hard drive where Windows is installed is otherwise recognized and works, but in this particular function it can't be used to upload images. I tried through the Firefox Instagram extension and through the separate Instagramport app. Same error on both.

Edit: The error message:

"Could not read the contents of.." and "Error opening directory '/media/my**** .. permission denied" ****=name of the drive
[image]

Comment: Does "*otherwise recognized and works*" mean that it's *mounted* to your Ubuntu system?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the error is. Maybe share a screenshot? Is the second hard drive mounted in Ubuntu? Like [@user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) has commented, it's not clear from the description if the drive is accessible from your Ubuntu (which would indicate it's probably mounted) or if you have to move the images to the 'ubuntu drive' from windows, indicating that the drive is probably not mounted.

Comment: Yes even if both partitions are active(mounted) it gives the error "Could not read the contents of.." and "Error opening directory '/media/my**** .. permission denied" ****=name of the drive.

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1270545/edit) to include your complete error message, AND the complete output of `ls -la /media/my****` . You can obscure filenames if you wish (we don't care what you call your stuff anyway), but don't obscure the ownership or permissions.

Comment: Now there is the screenshot too.

Comment: What web browser are you using for upload? Is it installed as a snap?
If yes, check if it works in a browser that is installed as a standard .deb package (like the Firefox installed by default).

Comment: That happens with both the independent Instagram port app not related to browser and with Firefox as well.

Comment: The Instagram port app was installed through Snap/Software Center. Maybe  I should try another one like Istekram?